# How to assign an object to another object using Scanner

Tags: java, object, java.util.scanner, aggregate, assign

I am writing a program for school where I have to associate two different objects from different classes. However, I want the user to assign an existing Owner object to the Dog while the user is creating the new Dog object using Scanner. I have two separate classes (one for Dog and one for OWner) and a tester Main.

```
public class DogOwnerTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Would you like to add a dog? (Enter 'Y' or 'N')");
        String add = input.next();

        while (add.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the dog: ");
            String name = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter the category of the dog: ");
            String category = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter the age of the dog: ");
            int age = input.nextInt();
            // System.out.println("Who is the dog's owner? ");
            // Somehow assign the owner to the dog using scanner?;

            Dog dog = new Dog(name, category, age, null);
            dogList.add(dog);

            System.out.println("Would you like to create another dog?(Enter 'Y' or 'N')");
            add = input.next();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `new ArrayList<>()` should be changed to `new ArrayList<Dog>()`.

Comment: @Gendarme No, it shouldn't.  The diamond operator is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Gendarme That is only true in ancient versions of Java.

Comment: Oh, I'm ancient already. Welp.

Comment: @azurefrog It will throw warnings in Linux during the compilation.(without `<Dog>`).

Comment: @KhanSaab It won't if you're using Java 7 or higher.

Comment: @azurefrog I use Java 8 and it's always the case! ;)

Comment: How could it throw *warnings*  before Java 7 anyway? It didn't exist then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , i think you want to assign a dog to the owner and not the owner to the dog.

Where is the owner of the dog? Create a list in the Owner's class and after creating the dog, add it to that list.

```
public class DogOwnerTester {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>(); // This list should be in user's class.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Create the owner object.
    Owner owner = new Owner(......); //Fill in the arguments



System.out.println("Would you like to add a dog? (Enter 'Y' or 'N')");
String add = input.next();

while (add.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the dog: ");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the category of the dog: ");
    String category = input.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the age of the dog: ");
    int age = input.nextInt();
    // System.out.println("Who is the dog's owner? ");
    // Somehow assign the owner to the dog using scanner?;

    Dog dog = new Dog(name, category, age, null);


    dogList.add(dog); // This should not be here.
    owner.addDogToList(dog);  //Call the owner's function to add the dog.

    System.out.println("Would you like to create another dog?(Enter 
            'Y' or 'N')");
    add = input.next();

    }
}
}
```

This function should be in owner's class.

```
public void addDogToList(Dog dog){
  this.dogList.add(dog);
}
```